# How to extend interface WebSocket from 'ws' library?

Tags: typescript

I try to extend an interface of a library but without success :(

Help me please!
I try to extend WebSocket interface from ws [library](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/ws/index.d.ts)

```js
...
declare class WebSocket extends events.EventEmitter {
   ...
}

declare namespace WebSocket {
   ...
}

export = WebSocket;
```

I need to add isAlive: boolean to WebSocket class

Try to:

import ws from 'ws';

```
declare module 'ws' {
    export interface WebSocket {
        isAlive: boolean;
    }
}
```

but it does not help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
interface WebSocket {
    online: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I originally posted it on github [github](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/1517#issuecomment-623148704).

```
declare module "ws" {
  class _WS extends WebSocket { }
  export interface WebSocket extends _WS {
      isAlive: boolean;
  }
}
```

though this will not work (since `WebSocket` here refers to the class, not the declared interface):

```
socket.on('connection', (ws: WebSocket, req: http.IncomingMessage) => {
    ws.isAlive = true;
}
```

while these do:

1. without type definition:

```
socket.on('connection', (ws, req: http.IncomingMessage) => {
    ws.isAlive = true;
}
```

2. with type definition (`WebSocket.WebSocket`):

```
socket.on('connection', (ws: WebSocket.WebSocket, req: http.IncomingMessage) => {
    ws.isAlive = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to create a class which extends WebSocket and cast to it. In `WebSocketEx.ts` add:

```
  import WebSocket from 'ws'

  export default interface WebSocketEx extends WebSocket {
    myProperty?: string
  }
```

Use it like this:

```
  import WebSocketEx from './WebSocketEx'

  fastify.get('/', { websocket: true }, function wsHandler(connection, req) {
    const socket = connection.socket // This is original WebSocket
    const socketEx = (socket as unknown) as WebSocketEx

    socketEx.myProperty = 'abcdef'

    socketEx.on('message', (message) => {
      log(`WS: message: ${JSON.stringify(message)}`)
    })
```